# error ASPPARSE: Could not load type error with msbuild on teamcity

Tags: asp.net, compiler-errors, msbuild, teamcity

I'm receiving error ASPPARSE: Could not load type error when building a project on team city.

The file it is failing on is a folder which is not referenced in the project but is just there for source control.

C:\TC\Agents\3\work\fd3ea8938fa12582>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler -v /DummyDeployWeb -p C:\TC\Agents\3\work\fd3ea8938fa12582\Project C:\TC\Agents\3\work\fd3ea8938fa12582\PreCompiled\Project-fixednames -u

ERROR
/DummyDeployWeb/common/files/somefilename.ascx(1): error ASPPARSE: Could not load type 'Project.somefilename'

How can I get the project to build and ignore these folders that arent referenced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET compiler knows nothing about project files, it simply processes the entire contents of the folder you point it at.

There is no way to tell the compiler to exclude specific files and so if this is a requirement for you then one solution would be to move these files out of the folder before you run the compiler and then copy them into the deployment folder after the compilation is complete.